# Integral solution of LP with two-sided inequality constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, integer-programming

I know the constraints matrix $A$ of a linear program 
$$
\min c^Tx \text{ subject to } b\le Ax
$$
is totally unimodular. So, the program has integral solutions for integral vector $b$.

Is this is also the case for the following problem:
$$
\min c^Tx \text{ subject to }  b_1\le Ax\le b_2
$$
where $b_1$ and $b_2$ are integral vectors and $A$ is totally unimodular. 
Does it have integral solutions, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be converted into standard form using slack variables $s_1$ and $s_2$. Then the two-sided problem is equivalent to
$$
\min c^Tx
$$
subject to
$$
\pmatrix{ A & -I &0\\ A& 0&I}\pmatrix{x\\s_1\\s_2} = \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}
$$
and
$$
x\ge0, \ s_1\ge0, \ s_2 \ge0.
$$
The matrix appearing above is totally unimodular:

- If $A$ is totally unimodular, then is $\pmatrix{-A\\A}$.
- If $B$ is totally unimodular, so is $\pmatrix{B & I}$.
- If $\pmatrix{C\\D}$ is totally unimodular, so is $\pmatrix{-C\\D}$.

These facts together prove that the system matrix above is totally unimodular as well.